# Rails HABTM additional data on relation

Tags: activerecord

I have a lessons table, and a users table, a lesson can have many students (users) and a student can have many lessons, so I store this in two models as follows

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'lesson_id', uniq: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lessons_signed_up, class_name: 'Lesson', foreign_key: 'user_id', uniq: true
end
```

And for that association I have a table

```
lesson_id | user_id
         1|       1 
         2|       1
```

But I also want to store the status of the lesson, if it was completed or not, so I'd use a table

```
lesson_id | user_id | completed
        1 |       1 | true
        1 |       2 | false
```

How can I add an extra attribute to the relation between lessons and users?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a habtm relationship, but a has_many :through. You can find information about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Basically, you make the relationship table into a model.